# Ubuntu 17.10: Neither WiFi nor Bluetooth works

Tags: networking, drivers, 17.10, bluetooth, iwlwifi

## Background

Going to just the normal settings application, it is clear that nothing is working with the WiFi or BT UI. The on/off switches don't work and no wifi or BT devices are visible. Thus I am having to dig deeper.

#### Regarding WiFi

I have an ASROCK Taichi X299 MoBo. The MoBo comes with WiFi and BT. However, it might be worth noting that in order to enable them in Windows (dual-booted system) I have to use ASROCK Network Utility (or something like that) that came on the driver install disc. I also plugged in my own dongle (which is still attached) just to see if I could get anything. Running `sudo lshw -class network` yields:

`*-network DISABLED

       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 10
       serial: a0:af:bd:c3:3f:52
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-38-generic firmware=29.610311.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:69 memory:92d00000-92d01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 03
       serial: 70:85:c2:52:23:df
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.4.0-k firmware=0. 4-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:17 memory:92c00000-92c1ffff ioport:3000(size=32) memory:92c20000-92c23fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 00
       serial: 70:85:c2:52:23:dd
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.2-4 ip=10.0.0.199 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:50 memory:92f00000-92f1ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enx00e04c680d9c
       serial: 00:e0:4c:68:0d:9c
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.09.9 duplex=half link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s`

Where the `DISABLED` network is the WiFi interface. Running `rfkill list` yields:

`0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes`

But I have no idea how I would remove the hard block on a desktop PC. Most of what I have seen to resolve this issue is in regard to laptops that have a corresponding physical "switch". Maybe there is something in the BIOS? (But I'm still not sure what to look for)

#### Regarding Bluetooth

What is interesting is the output of `rfkill list`, as stated above, does not give any information regarding bluetooth being blocked. However, if I run `lsusb`, I get several entries but namely the following:

`Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth`
I'm inclined to say that this is the dongle I plugged in, not the MoBo BT (which I couldn't find using `lshw`; though I could've missed it).

I have installed: `bluez-tools`, `bluez`, `bluez-cups`, `bluez-dbg`, `bluez-obexd`, `bluez-tests`, `libbluetooth3`, `libbluetooth3-dbg` `blueman`, `bluetooth` in Synaptic Package Manager. I installed Bluetooth Manager in Ubuntu Software in hopes it would know something I don't.

When trying to run Bluetooth Manager, I get:
"Connection to BlueZ failed - Bluez daemon is not running... no bluetooth adapters detected or Bluetooth daemon was not started."

If I run `sudo service bluetooth restart` and check with `sudo service bluetooth status`, I get the following:

`● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)`

I'm not sure how to force start the service (if that is my problem).

So, I'm not sure if the WiFi/BT issues are related but I cannot get either to work. Luckily, I am hooked up via ethernet but I would like to have the option for WiFi if I ever need it and BT just because. I realize this is alot to go through so all help is appreciated, thanks!

UPDATE: I just tried a different BT dongle I had lying around and it works. I guess neither the MoBo BT or other dongle I had was supported under linux. Would still like to know if maybe they would be with an extra setup but this other dongle will work for now.

EDIT:
`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` output:

`04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)`

`cat /etc/modules` output:

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
```

^ The file appears empty? should it be?

Comment: Please run the terminal command: `lsmod` As the output will be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Done, let me know if you can see it - https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BZBvnwMqQq/

Comment: May we also have a paste of: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `cat /etc/modules` Very interesting case here!

Comment: Please see above in prompt under EDIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your wireless card is an Intel, we see this in your `lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ath9k_htc              77824  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k_htc
ath9k_hw              471040  2 ath9k_htc,ath9k_common
ath                    28672  3 ath9k_htc,ath9k_hw,ath9k_common
mac80211              782336  1 ath9k_htc
wl                   6447104  0
cfg80211              614400  5 wl,ath9k_htc,mac80211,ath,ath9k_common
```

First, the correct driver for your device is iwlwifi, not wl, which is for a Broadcom device, not Intel. Please remove it:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -r wl
```

And load the correct driver:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

If there are any errors, please post them.

Is there any improvement? Does it survive a reboot without the USB dongle inserted?

```
rfkill list all
```

**EDIT**: In our chat, I suggested that you look in the BIOS to see if there were wireless settings. You learned that there is a WAN Radio option that was on Auto. You changed it to Enabled and, upon reboot, the rfkill was resolved and the wireless is now working.

Comment: It appears right now I am just getting a hang on `update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-38-generic` after `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source` and I'm scared to do a reboot.

Comment: should I just do it?

Comment: Is it still hanging? Can you take a picture of the screen and post it? https://imgur.com/upload Give me the link.

Comment: Ok, I rebooted and it stopped the hang, idk what the problem was... Anyway, I ran everything and wifi still comes up hardblocked but `sudo modprobe -r wl` yields: `modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.`

Comment: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
 Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
 Kernel modules: iwlwifi
`

Comment: `sudo lshw -c network
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 10
...
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-38-generic firmware=29.610311.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:67 memory:92d00000-92d01fff`

Comment: Is there any setting in the BIOS related to wireless? Is the `rfkill` result the same with the USB wireless removed?

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/m6FGB7czFq/

Comment: the usb dongle was only for BT, not for wifi

Comment: there are wireless settings but none the resemble "disabled"

Comment: What do the resemble?? I asked about the USB because this was in your first `lsmod`: ath9k_htc  That's a driver for an Atheros USB wireless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76041/discussion-between-chili555-and-sterling-butters).